# What are the exceptional cases when using Thread Pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

According to a known schedule, I need to call the `Run` method for a given list of tasks.

Currently I am using a Synchronous call from the main thread only.

```
foreach (var task in tasksToRunInCurrentBatch)
{
    Run(task.Key, task.Value);
}
```

This code will probably have to be improved since `tasksToRunInCurrentBatch` can have **more than 10k tasks**,
and I want to minimize the total time until last task was executed.

`Run` only executes the `Action` **of the task**, which should be simple, but is written in an external code, I have no influence about it, and it depends on the task.

I'm considering to use thread pool as a solution.

so i started by reading few articles - 
[How to: Use a Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.110).aspx) , 
[Using Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xt1dysy(v=vs.90).aspx)

Those articles explain the basics where everything looks too good. 
What are the exceptional cases when using Thread Pool within the current context?

Comment: Throwing ten thousand balls in the air and having none of them collide on the way down will indeed be exceptional.  You can't make this work reliably.

Comment: @HansPassant - Why would they "collide"?

Comment: Writing thread-safe code is hard.  Since the implementation of the code is entirely out of your reach, there isn't anything that you can do to ensure it is safe.

Comment: @HansPassant - "minimize the total time until last task was executed" - That is my purpose. Can opening new threads help to achieve that? If it can, there is something i can do.BTW - taking care of collision is something the Action creator deals with.

Comment: Have you tried `tasksToRunInCurrentBatch.AsParallel().ForAll(x => Run(x.Key, x.Value));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this extensive article on threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). Under section [Concurrent collections](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Concurrent_Collections) you can find an example of a `producer/consumer` queue that executes tasks.

As a general consideration you should not create 10k `Task` objects and `Run()` them all. Instead, create *n* `Task` instances that will execute the 10k methods you want to execute.

**EDIT**

If you want to use `ThreadPool` to execute the methods you want you'll have to take in consideration the following:

- what if one of your `Action`s throws an exception? `ThreadPool` does not marshal the exception to the calling thread so there is no way for you to catch it on the calling thread and it will bring your application down.
- how will you know that *all* the `Action`s are completed? `ThreadPool` does not offer a way to do this - it performs actions in a way that is very close to *fire and forget* strategy.

On the other hand `Task Parallel Library`, which is built on top of `ThreadPool` offers elegant ways to deal with the problems above. The `PCQueue` example from the link above ([Concurrent collections](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Concurrent_Collections)) shows you how to deal with exceptions thrown from the `Action`s you are invoking and provides a way to continue your application flow when *all* the actions are completed.

You can use `PCQueue` like this:

```
var queue = new PCQueue(Environment.ProcessorCount);
var tasks = tasksToRunInCurrentBatch.Select(t=>queue.Enqueue(t.Value)).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I don't see the words - Thread Pool in your answer.

Comment: @Yossi, that's because you probably should not use it. `Task`s use `TreadPool` internally but provide you with greater flexibility and reduced development overhead.

Comment: Even if the example isn't suffice, please try to answer the question.

Comment: @Yosi, please take a look at the latest edit. Maybe this will help you.